# Php-CodeIgniter Help needed

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am taking values form database in my php project. The values are taken and displayed fine. The problem is I have a button with each value. And I need a separate link for each button to see which data is selected. So that the functioning would depend on selected data. But each button gets the same name. This is my code.

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
<hr id="line">
<div id="wrong">
    <!--<button id="connect" type="submit">Connect</button>-->
<span id="name">    
<?php 
if($row->fname==$this->session->userdata('catgry'))
{?> 
    <span class="match"> <?php echo $row->fname; ?> </span>
<?php
}
else {
echo $row->fname;
$this->session->set_userdata('re_use',$row->fname);
}
?>
    &nbsp 
    <?php 
   if($row->lname==$this->session->userdata('catgry'))
{?> 


<span class="match"> <?php echo $row->lname; ?> </span>
<?php
}
else {
echo $row->lname;
}
?>
</span>
<!-- <select name="back_up">
<option selected><?php echo $row->userid ?></option>
<option>a</option>
</select>-->
<button id="connect" type="submit" >Connect</button>

</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please Help.

Comment: I don't get what your problem is, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: This should put on-hold. What you're asking is not clear.

Comment: I can help you but not getting exactly what output you want...

Comment: If you are talking about name of button then you can set it dynamic with php values. like <button name="<?php echo "name"?>".name variable will be dynamic.

Comment: I am displaying data from database and my database consists of users, their names, email addresses and a unique id for each user.
when I display them in a view using the loop I also display a button with each user (code given above) the purpose of the button is to connect with a specific user , now how to do that as their is only one same button in loop which is displayed again and again for all users but their are 20 distinct users

Comment: you cannot declare more than one submit type.Try to use type button instead of type submit for the button.

Comment: @Christian Mark what do you mean 'This should put on-hold'?

Comment: If your using `id="connect"` to have an event or anything, it will only give the values or attributes(whatever you are trying to get) of the last iteration of php loop, because `id` is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a hidden input and set the value to it on click of the button. You can store the value to the radio button and use it inside the JS function.

```
function setSelected(elm)
{
    document.getElementById('inputID').value = elm.value;
}
```

Outside the foreach loop.

```
<input type='hidden' name='SelectedUser' id='inputID' />
```

Inside loop, in the generated code for button.

```
<button id="connect" onclick='setSelected(this)' type="submit" value="<?php echo $row->userid; ?>">Connect</button>
```

In server side you can get the value using $_POST['SelectedUser'] when the page is submiited after selecting the user.

Comment: I need to access the specific id of user in controller.

Comment: Yes you can get it by using the hidden input field name. I have updated my answer to explain in detail.

Comment: Why the hidden input and javascript at all? By setting some "name" attribute to the button, he can use it to get the user id